# Missing dashboard option

Tags: thingsboard

I installed the ThingsBoard on window machine and when I log with admin account, I can't see the dashboard or customer like the demo.

So why can't I see the two options even that I'm using the admin account?

Answer (score 0):

All dashboards and customers in Thingsboard are tied to a Tenant. Thingsboard support multiple Tenants. When you are logged in as system administrator, Thingsboard can't know which of the tenants to show, so no dashboards or customers are shown.

The system administrator account is for system administration tasks, not for dashboard or customer tasks. If you want to manage dashboards or customers, login as the Tenant or Customer you want to manage.